# Error : "Document BlogPost may not be subclassed" mongoengine

Tags: python, django, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using pymongo version 2.6.1 with  mongoengine 0.8.4. And I want to create one code using tutorial given in

link https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

My code is as follows in sample.py file:

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

class BlogPost(Document):
    title = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    posted = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=50))

class TextPost(BlogPost):
    content = StringField(required=True)

class LinkPost(BlogPost):
    url = StringField(required=True)
```

On terminal wnen I run , I get follwing error:

Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from sample import Post
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "sample.py", line 9, in 
> > >           class TextPost(BlogPost):
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/base/metaclasses.py", line 332, in **new**
> > >           new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/base/metaclasses.py", line 120, in **new**
> > >           base.**name**) 
> > >       **ValueError: Document BlogPost may not be subclassed**

Please help me. I also tried uninstall and reinstall. but it not works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance), it seems that you need:

```
meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

in your `BlogPost` class.

Comment: Link to docs is dead. New doc location: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance